# Detecting Event from HTML Element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a legacy code that has something like

```
<a href='#' onclick="javascript:Domystuff(); return false;"> Some text<a>
```

I add a jQuery for some other purpose in website, and now I want to detect if this given a tag has "onclick" event available or not. But I didn't found how can I do this. I see most suggest to use `$("a").data('events')` but that didn't work for me, and always give undefined. however when I call `$("a").click()` it does execute the `Domystuff()` function.

Any idea how can I detect if `onclick` or `onchange` or `onblur` like HTML attribute events are present or not.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I don't just want to detect all events from attributes but I want all events on element for click or blur or change. Hope I make myself clear now. Thanks

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node

Comment: @simone not quite related, as I see, as I want to check if all events through code, not in debug environment.

Answer (score 2):

```
if($('a').attr('onclick')) { // exists
}
```

after all, even eventhandlers are HTML - attributes.
Still, that won't detect eventhandlers attached by jQuery, so:

```
 var ahrefs = $('a');
 for(var i = 0;i < ahrefs.length;i++) {
    var node = ahrefs.get(i);

    if(typeof node.onClick == function) { // has an attached event handler
    }
 }
```

Easy, isn't it?

Comment: +1, it is funny that I already think of it, but this doesn't quite solve my problem. but yes it is one of options to do. actually it is my fault I didn't mention that I want to detect all events doesn't matter how they get attached to element, not just with attribute. Atleast those who are added from jquery and attribute both.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
 if ($('a').attr("onClick") != undefined) {}
```

Comment: You can also try to be more specific in your selector.  `$("a")` is fairly greedy, but if you add a class `$("a.myClass")` it will only hit that element.